# How do I sync KDE 5 places (folder bookmarks) to GTK 3?

Tags: kde, sync, bookmarks, kde5, places

I'm using KDE 5 (plasma). How do I sync the folder bookmarks i made using Dolphin to GTK 3 applications such as Thunar?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F\" '/<bookmark href=\"file/ {print $2}' < $HOME/.local/share/user-places.xbel > $HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

See https://www.hemr.org/wiki/User:Ian/synchronizing_places_menu_in_dolphin_and_thunar for more info.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [BookmarkSync](https://github.com/jlu5/bookmarksync) application for that.

[image: BoomarkSync screenshot]

It is still useful in 2021, because some apps still do not support xdg desktop portal. And this may at least partly lower your pain of picking files in them.

It worth checking first if your app of interest supports native file picker. [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#Consistent_file_dialog) describes how to setup things.